# Email Template merge fields (Account.Name)

Tags: email-template, account, contact, merge-field

I have a lookup field of Account in the object Lead -- **Hotels__c**
I have also a lookup field of Contact in the object Lead -- **Applicant__c**

When trying to merge the {!Account.Name} in the HTML Email template, the Contacts' Account (Applicant__c.AccountId) is getting instead of the Hotels__c. Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to merge Lead fields? If yes, you should be using this: `{!Lead.Hotels__c}`  to get the respective Hotels__c value.

Comment: @ArnoldJr.
yeah. But i've want to get the address of that Lead.Hotels__c. When I'm trying to get, Lead.Hotels__r.ShippingAddress, the ShippingAddress was removed in the email template and it was replaced as Lead.Hotels__c by salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a Salesforce known issue. The workaround at this moment: You have to create a Formula field on the Child object, i.e, **Leads** to capture the field value from the Parent object that you wanted to display in the Email template.

References:

[Salesforce Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l1HbQAI)

[Salesforce Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk7AAC)

Comment: Jr Has this idea been implemented yet by Salesforce?

Comment: Nope. Not that I know of. Looks like the [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk7AAC) is under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

@JMRAF69, You can get shippingAddress field directly You have to call {!Lead.Hotels__r.ShippingCity}, {!Lead.Hotels__r.ShippingCountry}, {!Lead.Hotels__r.ShippingPostalCode} etc.